# Firebase reading and writing data for users in one collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I recently started a firebase project, and I need some help with the security rules. When A user signs up, I create a new document in a collection called "Users". The document name is encrypted by a server, and can only be decrypted by that same server. The problem I am having now is that if a malicious entity wanted to, they could get all of the documents in the collection by changing client-side code, and that would defeat the whole purpose of encrypting the data. So my question is: Is there a way to enforce that somebody can only read the data of their document in the collection, and block attempts to read the whole collection? (I am using Firestore by the way.)

Thanks so much!

FireBase Rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
   match /{document=**} {
     match /users/{userId} {

      //signed in users can get individual documents
      allow get: if request.auth.uid != null;

      //no one can query the collection
      allow list: if false;
      allow read, write;
     }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How are your [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) setup? Do you allow users to read and/or write data in the users collection beyond their own user?

Comment: I just have the most basic rules Read and Write. @AlexanderStaroselsky

Answer (score 1):

You're duplicating rules:

```
  //signed in users can get individual documents
  allow get: if request.auth.uid != null;

  //no one can query the collection
  allow list: if false;
  allow read, write;
```

Since `allow read` is a combination of `allow list` and `allow get`, that last line make the two lines above it useless.

The minimum change is to remove `read` from the allows:

```
  //signed in users can get individual documents
  allow get: if request.auth.uid != null;

  //no one can query the collection
  allow list: if false;
  allow write;
```

I suspect you'll want to tighten the `allow write` to only allow users to write their own document, but that's a separate problem.

Comment: Thank You So much!! This will work. I took out the read completely, and I kept write because users have to write data when they signup. Thanks again!